# Evaluate $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin(\frac{h}{2})-\frac{h}{2}}{h\sin(\frac{h}{2})}$ without l'Hospital

Tags: limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin(\frac{h}{2})-\frac{h}{2}}{h\sin(\frac{h}{2})}
$$

I've worked the last few hours on this equation and still didnt find a way to evaluate it.
The idea I had was to bound this expression like this:

$$
? \leqslant \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sin(\frac{h}{2})-\frac{h}{2}}{h\sin(\frac{h}{2})}\leqslant0
$$

If you could guide me maybe to find this expression or guide me on another track.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Essentially the same as https://math.stackexchange.com/q/94864/42969.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=h/2$. Famously (proven e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3167545) without any off-limits methods), $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}=-\tfrac16$. Since even more famously $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, you want$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x}{2x\sin x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x}{2x^2}=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Use Taylor series as needed.  Numerator $\approx \frac{-(h/2)^3}{3!}$, denominator $\approx \frac{h^2}{2}$.  Ratio $\to 0$ as $h\to 0$..

Answer (score 1):

This question can be solved by using the expansion of the function $\sin x$ which is as $$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+  \cdots  $$

Thus substituting $\frac{h}{2}$ in place of $x$ and then solving accordingly will give the answer.

[image: See graph]